# Graceful shutdown of IHostedService / BackgroundService

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ihostedservice

What is the best way to block shutdown of a service while jobs finish? I have a few background services that listen for messages on a message bus and handle processing.Some implement `IHostService` directly and some utilize `BackgroundService`

I know loops with a delay is absolutely not the best way, but this is the simplest illustration I can demonstrate. Another thought I had was a counter with number of total number of active jobs, but that would need a lock around it and I don't think that's a great idea either.

```
public interface IMessageBus
{
   Task<int> Subscribe(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
   Task Unsubscribe(int subscriptionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class Worker : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IMessageBus messageBus;
    private readonly List<Task> activeTasks;
    private CancellationTokenSource stoppingCts;
    int? subscriptionId;

    public Worker(ILogger logger, IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.messageBus = messageBus;
        this.activeTasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        this.logger.LogDebug("Subscribing to message bus.");
        this.subscriptionId = await this.messageBus.Subscribe(cancellationToken, this.Process);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.logger.LogDebug("Stopping Worker");

        // this will stop new messages coming in....
        if (this.subscriptionId.HasValue)
        {
            this.logger.LogDebug("Unsubscribed from message bus");
            await this.messageBus.Unsubscribe(this.subscriptionId.Value, cancellationToken);
        }

        // this should block until existing jobs finished....i don't like it though
        this.logger.LogDebug("Waiting for all jobs to finish");
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && this.activeTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            this.logger.LogDebug("Still waiting for all jobs to finish");
        }

        this.logger.LogDebug("Worker stopped.");
    }

    // this does real work, would be multiple running concurrently
    public async Task<bool> Process()
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Starting task..");

        var task = Task.Delay(100, this.stoppingCts.Token);
        this.activeTasks.Add(task);
        await task;
        this.activeTasks.Remove(task);

        this.logger.LogInformation("Task completed");

        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.stoppingCts?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to wait for all Tasks in the list to end? You can use Task.WhenAll, but check your example code first. In your example you will have at most one "active" task. You start a delay, add it to the list, wait for completion, and remove it from the list. There is no way to start a second task and add it to the list. Also base implementation of StopAsync will wait for completion of ExecuteAsync until StopAsync is cancelled.

Comment: Link to docs about BackgroundService https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class

Comment: @mcbr you are right, that was a bad example. I changed that to a closer sample or how we actually are implementing `IHostedService`. Main idea is that the `IHostedService` has many tasks fired off. There are ALOT of them, so I don't want to track them forever after the task is completed, so I don't think a `Task.WhenAll` is a good idea if the list is changing. Main change to example is messagebus now has a callback to trigger individual processing to show concurrency

Comment: I just want to add that reading/writing to a list is not thread safe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0#thread-safety

Comment: Also incrementing and decrementing a simple counter doesn't require locks when you are using static methods from `Interlocked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CountdownEvent` initialized with 1 and wait until it reaches zero [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/countdownevent#basic-usage). Increment the counter in the event when task is started, and decrement when finished using `AddCount` and `Signal` respectively. Just remember about last call to `Signal` in `StopAsync` to decrement the initial value.